# Understanding twisted differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, differential-forms

I'm trying to understand twisted differential forms.  I do know that they are like regular differential forms but under coordinate transformations they pick up an extra factor of the sign of the determinant of the transformation.  Somehow this means that they can be used to integrate on non-orientable manifolds. (???)

While Googling, I saw [this question on Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-is-charge-current-density-4-vector-a-twisted-differential-3-form.403164/), where one of the answers seems like a good start at understanding twisted differential forms.  I'll quote the answer here for reference.

> Consider a line segment. There are two ways one can orient this: along the segment and across the segment. For example, if you wanted to represent a segment of the world-line of a particle, then the first type of orientation is appropriate. On the other hand, imagine a circle drawn on a plane. A segment of this circle naturally has an orientation of the second type: it is oriented 'across' the segment, depending on which side of the circle is 'inside' and which is 'outside'
>
> This is the main difference between differential forms and their twisted counterparts, i.e. the type of orientation.
>
> The contour lines of a function have the 'across' orientation, and are represented by 1-forms. But if we wanted to represent coutour lines with an orientation along them instead of across, you would use a twisted 1-form.
>
> Imagine 2+1 dimensional spacetime. I assume you're familiar with the usual picture of a 2-form in a three dimensional space. The 'tubes' or 'boxes' in the picture of this 2-form will have an orientation that is 'around' them, i.e. clockwise or anticlockwise. Of course, one can always convert from clockwise/anticlockwise to up/down using things like right-hand rules, but that is not the natural type of orientation of a current. For a twisted 2-form, on the other hand, the tubes or boxes will have the correct 'along' orientation. So, in 2+1 dimensional spacetime, current density is a twisted 2-form. Similarly, in 3+1 dimensions, it is a twisted 3-form.

Though this isn't the way I usually think of differential forms, I am somewhat familiar with the geometric interpretation -- at least for $1$-forms -- as stacks through which vectors penetrate.  However I'm still not entirely able to see what a twisted differential $1$-form would be.  Geometrically, is it supposed to be like a curve which "counts" the projections of the tangent vectors onto the tangents of the curve along it?  If so, how is that picture obtained from the definition?  And how does one visualize higher dimensional twisted forms -- because I don't really understand that part of the post at all.

Comment: You might try looking at the discussion in [Abraham-Marsden-Ratiu](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387967905), if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Integral of a twisted differential $p$-form on a $p$-submanifold $\Sigma \subset M$ does not depend on the orientiation of $\Sigma$ (in fact $\Sigma$ can be non-orientable), but rather on external orientation (orientation of the normal bundle $\left. TM \right|_\Sigma / T \Sigma$). To give you a physical example of this, consider the current $j$ of certain substance (e.g. water or electric charge) in a container $M$ (manifold of dimension $D$). I claim that $j$ is geometrically a twisted $(D-1)$-form on $M$. Indeed, given any two-sided hypersurface $\Sigma \subset M$, the flux $\int_\Sigma j$ of the flowing substance through $\Sigma$ is well-defined. Clearly it should not depend on the orientation of $\Sigma$, but it should change sign if we switch which side of $\Sigma$ is regarded as "in" vs "out".

Of course twisted $D$-forms are even easier: they represent densities and can be integrated over volume, without having to choose orientation. One example is the volume form: certainly given a metric you can calculate the area of a Mobius strip! To extend my previous physical analogy, suppose that the substance under consideration has density profile $\rho$. Then $\rho$ is a twisted $D$-form. If the amount of substance is (pointwise) conserved, we will have a continuity equation $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho + d j=0, $$ in which $d$ is the exterior derivative along the "spatial" manifold $M$ and $t$ is additional "time" parameter. This equation is the statement that the rate of change of amount of the substance in some volume $\Omega$ is given by the flux of the substance through boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the questions at the end of the post, but rather an answer to the question marks in

> Somehow this means that they can be used to integrate on non-orientable manifolds. (???)

Namely, I want to expand on the mathematical details of why exactly this property allows $n$-pseudoforms to be integrated on any smooth $n$-manifold without having to make additional choices.
For this I need the machinery of associated bundles.

### Associated bundles $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$ $\newcommand\id{\mathrm{id}}$ $\newcommand\sgn{\mathrm{sgn}}$

The frame bundle $LM$ on a manifold $M$ is a principal $GL(n)$-bundle: there is a fibrewise regular (i.e. free and transitive) right $GL(n)$-action on $LM$, a matrix $A\in GL(n)$ sends a frame $e=(e_i)$ to the new frame $e\triangleleft A=(\sum_j e_jA^j_i)$.

If $GL(n)$ acts on a vector space $V$ by a representation $\rho:GL(n)\to GL(V)$, then you can construct a new vector bundle $LM[V,\rho]\to M$ as
$$LM[V,\rho] = (LM\times V)/\sim$$
where the relation $\sim$ is given by $(e\triangleleft A,v)\sim(e,\rho(A)v)$ or, equivalently, as $(e,v)\sim(e\triangleleft A,\rho(A^{-1})v)$. Write the equivalence class of $(e,v)$ as $[e,v]$.

This construction allows us to "tie a vector bundle to its components with respect to $LM$" as follows:

Since for any two $[e,v]$, $[e',v']$ in $LM[V,\rho]$ (over the same basepoint) there is a unique $A\in GL(n)$ such that $e\triangleleft A=e'$ (because the action is regular) it follows that, given a local section $X$ of $LM[V,\rho]$ and a local section $F$ of $LM$, for every point $p$ of (an open subset $U$ of) the manifold, you can find a unique vector $X_F(p)\in V$ such that
$$X(p) = [F(p),X_F(p)].$$
Indeed, if $X(p)=[e,v]$, then let $X_F(p)=\rho(A^{-1})v$, where $A$ is the unique matrix in $GL(n)$ such that $e\triangleleft A=F(p)$. This gives us a function $X_F:U\to V$ whis is the "components of $X$ with respect to $F$". I'll write this as
$$X = [F,X_F]$$
which holds at the domain of $F$.

If $F:U\to LM$ is the local frame associated to a coordinate frame $(U,x)$, then write $F=\partial/\partial x$.

Now you take $V=\R^n$ and the standard representation $\id:GL(n)\to GL(\R^n)$, then you can express a section $X$ of $LM[\R^n,\id]$ using a local coordinate frame $\partial/\partial x$ as
$$\begin{align}
 X = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},X_{(x)}\right]
\end{align}$$
where $X_{(x)}:U\to\R^n$ are the "components of $X$ with respect to $\partial/\partial x$".

Notice the following: if you take a new coordinate patch $y$ on $U$, then you have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\triangleleft
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
$$

$$\begin{align}
X
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},X_{(x)}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\triangleleft
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x},X_{(x)}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y},
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}X_{(x)}\right] \\
\end{align}$$

but also
$$
X = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y},X_{(y)}\right]
$$

hence

$$
X_{(y)}
=
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}X_{(x)}
$$
or, in components,
$$
X_{(y)}^i
=
\sum_j \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}X^j_{(x)}
$$
which is precisely the "transformation behaviour" of a tangent vector field. Indeed, you can show that $LM[\R^n,\id]$ is isomorphic to the tangent bundle $TM$.

---

### Case of interest

Now take an $n$-form $\omega$, i.e. a section of the bundle of $n$-forms $\bigwedge^n T^*M$.

If $(U,x)$ is a coordinate chart, you can express $\omega$ locally as
$$\omega = \omega_{(x)} dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n.$$
where $\omega_{(x)}:U\to\R$ is a function of the manifold that depends on the chart map $x$. If you change coordinates to a new chart map $y$, then $\omega$ has the new expression
$$
\omega
= \omega_{(y)} dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n
$$
which is related to the old one by
$$\begin{align}
\omega
&= \omega_{(x)} dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n \\
&= \omega_{(x)} \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^{i_1}}dy^{i_1}
\wedge\dots\wedge \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial y^{i_n}}dy^{i_n} \\
&=\omega_{(x)} \det\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n.
\end{align}$$
So
$$\omega_{(y)}
=
\det\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)
\omega_{(x)}
=
\det\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}
\omega_{(x)}
.$$
What this is saying is that the bundle $\bigwedge^n T^*M$ can be obtained as an associated bundle to the principal bundle $LM$ via the representation $\rho:GL(n)\to GL(1)=\R^*$ given by $\rho(A)v = \det(A)^{-1}v$, because for this associated bundle $LM[\R,\rho]$ you have
$$\begin{align}
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\omega_{(x)}\right]
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\triangleleft\frac{\partial y}{\partial x},\omega_{(x)}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\rho\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)\omega_{(x)}\right].
\end{align}$$
but also
$$\begin{align}
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\omega_{(x)}\right]
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\omega_{(y)}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\det\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\omega_{(x)}\right].
\end{align}$$

Similarly, you can check that if you take the representation $\sigma:GL(n)\to GL(1)=\R^*$ given by $\sigma(A)=|\det A|^{-1}$, then the component functions $\mu_{(x)}$ and $\mu_{(y)}$ of a section $\mu$ of $LM[\R,\sigma]$ with respect to coordinate charts $x$ and $y$ obbey the transformation law
$$\mu_{(y)}
=
\left|\det\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right|
\mu_{(x)}
.$$
Now you can define the integral of $\mu$ over $U$ as
$$\int_U \mu = \int_{x(U)} \mu_{(x)}\circ x^{-1}$$
where the right hand side is the Lebesgue integral in $\R^n$. Now this is independent of the chart maps because if $y$ is any other chart map defined on $U$ whatsoever (in particular, it can be orientation reversing) then you have $y(U)=y\circ x^{-1}\circ x(U)$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{y(U)} \mu_{(y)}\circ y^{-1}
&= \int_{y\circ x^{-1}\circ x(U)} \mu_{(y)}\circ y^{-1} \\
&= \int_{x(U)} (\mu_{(y)}\circ y^{-1}\circ (y\circ x^{-1}))|J(y\circ x^{-1})| \\
&= \int_{x(U)} (\mu_{(y)}\circ x^{-1}) \left|\det\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\circ x^{-1}\right| \\
&= \int_{x(U)} \left(\mu_{(y)}\left|\det\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|\right)\circ x^{-1} \\
&= \int_{x(U)} \mu_{(x)}\circ x^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$
The bundle given by this representation $\sigma(A)=|\det A|^{-1}$ is called the $1$-density bundle or also the $n$-pseudoform bundle. Its sections are called $1$-densities or $n$-pseudoforms.

My comments about twisting the bundle of $n$-forms $\bigwedge^n T^*M$ with the bundle given by the representation $A\mapsto \sgn(\det A)$ is basically due to the fact that the representation $\sigma$ that gives rise to $n$-pseudoforms can be decomposed as
$$
\sigma(A)=|\det A|^{-1} = \sgn(\det A)\det(A)^{-1} = \sgn(\det A)\rho(A)
$$
where $\rho$ is the representation that gives rise to the $n$-form bundle $\bigwedge^n T^*M$.

Comment: Is there a name, or at least a more concrete description for *the line bundle associated to the character A ↦ sgn(det(A))* that you mention under Mozibur's answer? I find the approach with defining the twisted forms as $\wedge T^* M\otimes E$ for a suitable $E$ easier to grasp (I get a bit lost still at the time you introduce the factor space $(LM\times V)/\sim$).

Comment: Actually I think I know what you're doing in your answer, just in other terms. Do you mean that the $E$ (in $\wedge T^*M\otimes E$) is constructed as the associated (to $\wedge^m T^*M$) bundle by the absolute value map $g_x:GL(T_x(\wedge^m T^*M)=\mathbb R)\to GL(\mathbb R^*), g_x(r)=|r|$? (sorry if this is badly written, I learned about associated bundles from an old book which did it using $GL(F')\to GL(F)$ transformations and I suppose they somehow correspond to your principle bundle argument)

Answer (score 1):

Given a manifold $M$, differential forms over it are the sheaf of sections of the exterior cotangent bundle:

> $\Omega(M) := \Gamma(\wedge T^*M)$

Given a vector bundle $E$ over the same manifold, we say the exterior tangent bundle is twisted by $E$ when we form:

> $\wedge T^*M \otimes E$

Then again taking sections we define differential forms over $M$ twisted by $E$.

> $\Omega(M,E) := \Gamma(\wedge T^*M \otimes E)$

These are also called differential forms valued in $E$. Now one important case is when $E$ is actually a line bundle. And an important such line bundle is:

> $Or(M) := \wedge^m T^*M$

Where $m$ is the dimension of the manifold. Thos os the orientation bundle. Now differential forms twisted by $Or(M)$, that is $\Omega(M, Or( M))$, are called densitised forms. These are the forms you are interested in. Its this twisting by the orientation bundle that allows it to be integreted over non-orientable manifolds.

Comment: I don't think densitised forms have the correct transformation property. Shouldn't you twist the $k$-forms by the line bundle associated to the character $\rho(A)=\mathrm{sgn}(\mathrm{det}(A))$ instead?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: I think the forms twisted by the orientation bundle are the same as forms twisted by the character you name.

Comment: No, the bundle $\bigwedge^m T^*M$ is associated to the character $A\mapsto \det(A)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Jackozee Hakkiuz: Hmm, did you read what I wrote in the post? I wrote "$\Omega(M, Or(M))$. So why are you telling me about the character of "$\Omega^(M)$"?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: Before shouting "No" you might want to reread what I wrote ...

Comment: Sorry if it read as if I was shouting. I'll have another read.

Comment: Now I did read it again. In your post you mention forms $\Omega(M,E)$ twisted by some vector bundle $E$. You take $E=\bigwedge^m T^*M$, which is associated to the character $A\mapsto \det(A)^{-1}$. I'm saying you should instead take $E$ as the line bundle associated to the character $A\mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(\det(A))$.

I hope this clears up the confusion. And sorry if my lasts posts sounded rude. It wasn't my intention.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: Well, the definition of densitised form in [NLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+form) is "the bundle $\Omega^n(X)$... is itself a line bundle which is associated to the frame bundle by the character $A \rightarrow det(A)^{-1}$; a p-form twisted by this line bundle is called a *densitised  form*" and this is exactly my definition above.

Comment: Yes, we both agree in what densitized forms are. But my point is that the "things that you can integrate" are not densitized forms but instead what you *can* integrate naturally are $1$-densities or, equivalently, top degree pseudoforms, which you obtain when you twist by $A\mapsto\mathrm{sgn}(\det(A))$. Hopefully now my first comment (from jul 15) makes more sense?

Comment: No, we don't - unfortunately. Nlab also intoduces a sign and they appear to be a bit confused in their terminology about densities and densitised forms; nevertheless, the determinant in all their expressions is inverted - whereas yours, as you have written above, does not. I think we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Hi @Mozibur. I just wrote an answer where I elaborated my point. I thought you may be interested in taking a look.